# How do I get mobile AR mode working in qgis2threejs?

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I've created a map in qgis and exported using qgis2threejs and the mobile template. Everything renders fine in the browser (laptop and phone). Rotation, pan and zoom work as expected. When I load the page in the browser on my phone (iPhone 6s Plus, iOS 12.1.4), the map renders and I get a slider control for AR (augmented reality) in the upper right, a cross-hairs button for GPS location, and settings control. If I tap the cross-hairs, the current GPS position is displayed in a dialog, but the location is not indicated on the map, nor does the map shift position/orientation. If I enable the AR slider, I get a popup asking permission to use the camera. I click yes, and the screen goes black.

I've tried exporting in the map CRS (UTM 13N) and also enabling lat/lon conversion. Same results either way.

Any clues on what supposed to happen and how to make this work?

qgis 3.4.2, current version of qgis2threejs from plug-ins repository

Comment: I am looking at doing the same thing as you mention above (same as VGIS is doing). Have you managed to solve the problem? I would be very interested in hearing how you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation available [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/qgis2threejs/downloads/pdf/docs/) (page 20); you need to upload the folder on a server that accepts SSL. I did try to upload the the folder into my Android phone and run it, the AR functionality did not work.
I uploaded into our web server and started the link with http**s**:// and it works fine.
Also, I have tested with Firefox on Android, it does not work or I need to do some settings on my Pocophone. Chrome and Xiaomi browsers work just fine.

[image]